# Bus Error(Core Dumped)

Tags: command-line, apt, 17.04

Please I need help urgently... I can't install or update anything, my system just prints out

> Bus Error(Core Dumped)

I don't recall doing anything weird before the error started coming up, please help.

Comment: You might mean (Core Dumped) instead of Dumoed... in the title :)

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just ran

> sudo apt-get update

and everything became a-okay.

Answer (score -2):

I deleted a ".electroneum" folder on my Home directory to start afresh. This will sync from the beginning after deletion. Press (Ctrl+H) to toggle hidden contents and look for it.