# APT-GET UPGRADE DPKG errors. Ubuntu 18.04 Server

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg

This is my first askubuntu question! I'm on here quite a bit but usually I can figure my problem out through one of the posts, but not this time.

I was performing my usual manual updates which besides today I've had no issues. I tried the usual `apt-get -f install` for fix any errors but no luck.

Please help.

```
sudo] password for steve: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic (4.15.0-36.39) ...
Bus error (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 135
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-36-generic:
 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-36-generic depends on linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic | linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-36-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic is not configured yet.
  Package linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-36-generic is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-36-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency prNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                             No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                       No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                     oblems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 4.15.0.36.38); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-36-generic
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Maybe related? https://askubuntu.com/questions/929929/bus-errorcore-dumped

Comment: I suspect some memory error (try using `memtest`). If you are in VM, the could be more problems. You needto detail more your environment.

Comment: No I'm running this on a Dell OmiPlex desktop from 2010-2011. 4gb ram 3ghz processor 80gb hd. I use it as a media / file headless server

Answer (score 0):

try

`sudo apt-get update` first.

Then inform what happened.
It also seems  you got more problems

`Bus error (core dumped)`

Comment: here's my apt-get update sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for steve: 
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]   
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB] 
Fetched 247 kB in 1s (204 kB/s)                              
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: Well, did you run upgrade after that?